# Which tools to use to list pricing for all lineageOS ROMs?

Tags: bash, grep, restful-url, lineageos

I am going to buy a new smartphone which shall run [lineageOS](https://lineageos.org/). Because the decision about the right smartphone is always guided by the pricing of the phone I would like to generate a pricing list containing all devices supported by lineageOS.

To make is super clear: This question is **not** about an exact step by step instruction. It is about finding the right technologies/tools to get the work done.

**Which tools to use to list pricing for all lineageOS ROMs?**

---

The only tools that I know to use to generate such a list are ´grep´ and ´wget´ in a ´bash´ environment. This is not the most efficient way to get the work done and I hope someone else can show up more suitable tools. Nevertheless here is my receipt to generate the list:

1. Using `wget` to download the [devices homepage](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/) or the [lineageOS statistics web service](https://stats.lineageos.org/)
2. Using `awk` and/or grep to filter out of the homepages source code a plain list of all devices
3. Using a `bash` for-loop calling `wget` for every device string into the restFull-API (is this really the right name for that technologie?) of *idealo* or *amazon*. This may look like this:

   `for device in $DEVICES; do wget https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=$device > $device.html`
4. Using `grep` to find the line with the device's price by filtering for the first search item. This may as ugly as this:

   `grep -A999999 pageContent-wrapper device.html | grep -m1 -A2 ">price-prefix" | grep "€"`
5. Using `cut` to extract the price itself from the line
6. Output a well formatted list by using something like this:

   `echo $device $price`

Comment: I don't see a shortcut around getting each device's data and that seems to be the bottleneck for time. Your general idea seems like it will work. If you need this soon, go ahead and do that, so at least you're getting something. If this is the only thing you have to work on, then you can use your first 10+ devices to see if there are any optimizations you can do and then recode to take advantage. Good luck.

Comment: To parse html, use a proper parser like in my answer

Answer (score 2):

### Here we go, using a proper HTML parser and [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) :

```
while read device; do
  printf '%s %s\n' "$device" $(
  saxon-lint --html --xpath '(//div[@class="offerList-item-priceMin"])[1]/text()' \
  "https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=$device"
)
done < <(
  saxon-lint --html --xpath '//a[starts-with(@href, "/model")]/text()' \
  https://stats.lineageos.org/
)
```

Check [saxon-lint](https://github.com/sputnick-dev/saxon-lint)

### Output

```
m8 128,22 €
bacon 1,89 €
riva 224,99 €
cancro 8,35 €
klte 
j7eltexx 
t0lte 
wt88047 
i9300 35,58 €
mido 558,00 €
...
```

### Note

Testing `a5y17lte` (by example) via https://www.idealo.de/preisvergleich/MainSearchProductCategory.html?q=a5y17lte there's no result.

The site is not reliable, an another example: `bacon 1,89 €` is not a phone :D

Another working tool is `xidel` :

```
xidel -e '//a[starts-with(@href, "/model")]/text()' https://stats.lineageos.org/
```